# MapView not being removed from ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In my application I'm trying to implement a map view inside a ViewPager. I have 4 different pages in the application. and MapView is in the 4th page. I did successfully load the map, but when I swipe back to the first page the 4th view must be destroyed using destroyItem() method. And if I swipe to the 4th page, it crashes from 3rd page showing an error in the logcat:

```
05-10 13:14:50.152: E/AndroidRuntime(620): java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are only allowed to have a single MapView in a MapActivity
```

Im aware of having only a single mapview in a MapActivity. But I'm not able to solve it - can anyone help me?

Code is below :

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   context = collection.getContext();
   int resId = 0;
   int flag = resId;
   switch (position) {
   case 0:
      resId = R.layout.farleft; // first
      view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

      break;
   case 1:
      resId = R.layout.left; // second
      view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

      break;
   case 2:
      resId = R.layout.right; // third
      view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

      break;
   case 3:
      resId = R.layout.mylocator;
      view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
      break;

   }
   ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

   return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {

   ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
   Log.d("destroyItem", "" + arg2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.
Inside your fragment which contains the Map and that is used by the ViewPager, put that :

```
private View myView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (this.myView == null){
        this.myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
    }
    else if (this.myView.getParent() != null) {
        FrameLayout parentView = (FrameLayout) this.myView.getParent();
        parentView.removeView(this.myView);
    }

    return this.myView;

}
```

It works fine for me, tell me if it works for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

One issue with the Android View Pager is that recycling views has to be done manually. In your case it is possible that the view has not been destroyed yet but is created a second time when the view is instantiated again. You could save your view for each page and then return it in instantiateItem if it hasn't been destroyed already.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I have tried this with @Seppl answer without success :

    HashMap<Integer, Object> itemList;

public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        
  if(itemList.get(position) != null ){
   return itemList.get(position);
  }
  Object viewGroup = super.instantiateItem(container, position);  
  itemList.put(position, viewGroup);
  
  return viewGroup;
  
 }

EDIT : How can I format code in a comment ?