# Android. How to show MapView with ViewPager nested on TabHost

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-viewpager

I need develop next situation: i have main_screen.xml with TabHost, wich have two (or more) Tabs - each of them have as root element ViewPager.

ViewPager have two (or more) pages next sequence MainViewList->DetailView->MapView and go back MapView->DetailView->MainViewList (M->D->M)

There i have problem: on the first pass all works fine, but after again M->D->M it's crashes with exception than Only One MapView can be inflated with MapActivity.

I check with debug that method destroyItem on ViewPagerAdapter works corects - it's remove MapView from parentView (ViewPager).

Also then i go Map->D->M i remove from list of screens in ViewPagerAdapter prevscreen - so i can't return to screen if slide to left (first screen, or DetailView after MapView,i can't slide back to MapView - i need this logic works).

Also you can see this post [MapView not being removed from ViewPager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530087/mapview-not-being-removed-from-viewpager) with same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have found next solution

ViewPager is part of any Activtiy, so i create activity next code

```
class FirstTabActivityWithMap extends MapActivity{
 MapViewHolder mpViewHolder;//Extends ViewHolder and contains MapView inflated from layout resource

protected void onCreate(...){
// Create view pager
 myViewPager=new ViewPager();//And etc init Pager

//Some code witch create mpViewHolder - it's depend of yours needs
 setContentView(myViewPager);
}

//Here is magic :)
public void someActionWichNeedAddScreenWithMap(){

 //Remove current map from prev parent 
 if (mpViewHolder.currentView.getParent() != null) {
    ((ViewPager) mpViewHolder.currentView.getParent())
        .removeView(mpViewHolder.currentView);
    }
    this.myViewPager.addScreen(mpViewHolder);//Adding screen and call notifyDataSetChanged()
 }

}
```

This code ((ViewPager) mpViewHolder.currentView.getParent()).removeView(mpViewHolder.currentView);
have one problem - it's you always will work with same MapView instance.